# Kotlin - BottomNavigationView uncheck all items

Tags: android, kotlin, menuitem, checked, bottomnavigationview

I got a problem on unckeck all items in bottom navigation. I've tried multiple codes, for exemple:

```
 val bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView
 bottomNavigationView = conteudo_feridas.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.nav_bottom_cartao_tipo) as BottomNavigationView

 val size = bottomNavigationView.menu.size()
 for (i in 0 until size) {
     bottomNavigationView.menu.getItem(i).isChecked = false
 }
```

**Nothing works**. I want all the items to have the same size, and in the default case, the checked one gets bigger. I'm trying to reach the following effect:

[image]

Can you help me, please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what is the version of the support library you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your **dimen.xml** just add below two line

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">14sp</dimen>
```

it will work exactly you want

you can change size according to your requirement

If you give the same size it will appear same in selected and nonselected item

Comment: Thank you so much!